# Downloading PostgreSQL Mac Download Error

Tags: sql, macos, postgresql, installation, pip

could you please advise me of a solution you may know for downloading PostgreSQL. I am trying to install 9.6.5 version, but also tried the 10.0, same error.

I am using an installation option for Mac operating system OS Sierra from website: https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/postgresql/installers.jsp/

I am getting an error:
[image]

Have tried to run the instruction sudo easy_install pip in the command line and it installs the pip file successfully. However I am still unable to install the PostgreSQL.

Please could you advise what the issue may be?

I have also installed Homebrew (it did not help).
I do already have anaconda and Python installed, as well as latest versions of R and RStudio.

Answer (score 1):

I have now found a solution to the above problem (on Mac). Execute the following command in your terminal:

sudo easy_install-2.6 pip

If that does not work execute:

sudo easy_install-2.7 pip

This allows the PostgreSQL to be downloaded correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions suggesting using easy_install-2.7 but still got an error very similar to that from the OP. I had to specifically install pip 9.0.0 with

sudo easy_install-2.7 pip=9.0.0

after which the PostgreSQL install worked.
The default pip is now v10, so it's probably a string compare issue in the installer.

Comment: it doesn't look like answer to question posted. post more details on how to fix the OP's question

Comment: Actually it is, Postgres installer is asking for pip 9.0.0 even if you have pip 10+ installed, which is very annoying

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me on Mac High Sierra 10.13.4:

1. Clear out the brew cache `$ rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew`
2. Clear out the site-packages `$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
3. Reinstall Python `$ brew reinstall python` This pulls down `python-3.5.6.high_sierra` and put it in `/usr/local/bin/python3`
4. But `which python` still shows `/usr/bin/python`
5. The **solution** is to run `$ brew install python@2` which pulls down `python@2-2.7.14_3.high_sierra`
6. Now `which python` shows the correct path `/usr/local/bin/python` which is also where all your pip stuff is installed, so now pip will work.
7. Ensure the latest version of pip is installed with `$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip`